# how to add a @ManyToOne column in json response with springboot?

Tags: spring-boot

I have 2 entities :
`Contract` and `ContractItems`, defined like this :

```
 @JoinColumn(name = "CONTRACT_ID", nullable = false)
 @ManyToOne
 private Contract contract;

@JsonIgnore
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "contract", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private List<ContractItem> details;
```

and when i show the list of contractItems the `contract` fields do not appear. here is my controller and the called functions :

```
   @PostMapping(path = "/All/{id}", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
   @ApiImplicitParams({@ApiImplicitParam(name = "Authorization", value = "Bearer bcryptjwttoken", paramType = "header",required=true), @ApiImplicitParam(name = "Accept", value = "application/json", paramType = "header",required=false),@ApiImplicitParam(name = "Content-Type", value = "application/json", paramType = "header",required=true)
}) 

public WsResponse<List<ContractItem>> findAll(@PathVariable Long id){
    Account account=accountService.findById(id);
    if(account!=null) {
    try { 
        List<Contract> contract=co.findByAccount(account);
        List<ContractItem> contract2  = new ArrayList<ContractItem>();
        if(contract!=null) {
            
    for(Contract co : contract) {
        contract2.addAll(coi.findByContract(co));
        
    }
        }else {
            throw new DataNotFoundException("Aucun contrat trouvé pour ce compte");
        }
        
        return new WsResponse<List<ContractItem>>(contract2);
        
    }catch (FonctionnalException e) {
        throw new FonctionnalException(e.getMessage());
    }
    }else {
        throw new DataNotFoundException("Aucun compte trouvé avec cet identifiant "+id);
    }
    
    
}
```

and the functions :

on the account repository : `List<Contract> findByAccount(Account account);`

on the countractItem repository : `public List<ContractItem> findByContract(Contract contract);`

the controller shows the list of contractItems but without contract fields altough there is that field in entity.

Comment: It will work out of the box - but not thanks to Spring in any way, but thanks to Jackson that is used by default as entity json mapper. Your problem is, there is NO data to serialize. Either your data is incorrect, or you think that you have saved something, but you did it wrong/didnt do that at all.

Comment: in database there is a link between contract and contractItems, i created contractItems with existing contractId so i don't think the data is incorrect

Comment: a contractItem cannot be registered without a contractId

Comment: Don't lie to yourself - its a data/mapping issue.